# How to manually setup Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04 Dual Boot under UEFI

Tags: windows-10, grub2, dualboot, ubuntu-22.04

> **Note**: *Please read the full post with due diligence before posting comments/answers or downvoting/closing this question. In case your solution pertains to using some third party boot manager please ignore this question as that is not what I am looking for.*

**Premise**:

I first installed Windows 10 on my notebook-PC which created the EFI and other system partitions. I also created an extra partition. Once Windows was setup, I proceeded to install Ubuntu 22.04 on the extra partition; instead of choosing the "*Install alongside Windows*" option, I used the "*Something else*" option to complete the installation. Ubuntu installer created a directory called `ubuntu` under the **EFI** directory on the eponymous partition.

**Desired Outcome**:

The dual boot functionality only works if I use the firmware boot manager (*the one that can be accessed from the UEFI boot up screen by pressing some Fx key on startup*). I want the Ubuntu OS entry to show up under the Windows Boot Manager.

**What I tried**:

Using the `bcdedit` tool in windows I performed the following steps:

1. `bcdedit /copy {bootmgr} /d "Ubuntu 22.04"` <--- *returns a guid*
2. `bcdedit /set {guid} path "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"`

Although an entry for Ubuntu 22.04 shows up in the Windows Bootloader Menu, when I select it, after a restart, the error message thrown is:

```
.
.
.

Status: 0xc000007b

Path: \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

Message: The required file is missing or corrupted...
```

**Perceived Problem**:

I did some digging and I think the problem is this: chainloading error.

When the Windows Boot Manager tries to load the GRUB loader, the `grub.cfg` file at `\EFI\ubuntu\` tries to find a filesystem with an ID assigned by Ubuntu (*whereas Windows assigns a different ID to the same partition for ubuntu*). So, when attempting to load the `shimx64.efi` Windows Boot Manager simply fails to find the required files.

**Possible Solution**:

This is where I need help - I think the problem can be solved by copying over some required files (say the *mod* files and actual *grub.cfg*) from the actual Ubuntu partition, into the EFI partition. So, the question is, which files and exactly what file structure?

---

**Update**: *To view contents of EFI partition*

Open command prompt in Windows with admin priviledges, then type in the following:

```
$> mountvol Y: /S
$> Y: 
Y:\> cd EFI\ubuntu\
Y:\EFI\ubuntu\> dir
```

once you are done, you might want to remove the drive letter mount point:

```
Y:\EFI\ubuntu\> C:
C:> mountvol Y: /d
```

Comment: The details at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/571173) give some insights, but, does not solve the problem!

Comment: Try [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/), free for personal non-commercial use.

Comment: @harrymc EasyBCD does NOT work well under strict EFI conditions - used to work well back in MBR era.

Comment: The article [EasyBCD and UEFI](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/) says this : "If your Windows PC is booting in EFI mode, **Microsoft has blocked the loading of legacy or non-Windows operating systems from the BCD menu**". This means that it's impossible to add a Linux distribution to the Windows bootloader. Why are you not using GRUB as the bootloader, rather than Windows?

Comment: I am aware of the stated limitation by EasyBCD. However, I think it still can be done. Besides, I want WBM as the default since primarily I am setting this notebook-PC as a Windows machine with Ubuntu as the secondary OS. Also, I wish to figure out what makes it impossible.

Comment: So you wish to hack Windows and undo a limitation that Microsoft purposefully enforced in Windows. Your chances are not good.

Comment: Not necessarily hack/remove limitation. I think the problem is very practical - Windows Boot Manager is unable to find the Ubuntu partition using an ID that was generated by Ubuntu. If I can figure out how it was done back in MBR days, it might still be done!

Comment: In case I am not very clear, have a look at the `\EFI\ubuntu\grub.cfg` file on the EFI partition.

Comment: Back in MBR days there was no such limitation by Microsoft, so this was possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146418/discussion-between-anurag-and-harrymc).

Comment: Alternatively you may consider opting for boot managers like rEFInd. https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ You may need to disable secure boot.

Comment: I am very specific as to what I intend to achieve: Ubuntu entry in Windows Boot Manager. Kindly ignore the question in case you do understand how _chainloading_ of Boot Managers work. Kindly DO NOT suggest third party apps.